# Running FlyWay in CI\CD pipeline on different ENVs

Tags: sql-server, continuous-integration, devops

I want to create a CI\CD pipeline using a GIT repo and flyway.

I have a DEV server and TEST server (both SQL Servers), and I want to take the scripts that were developed in DEV env (from the shared GIT repo after committing from dev) and run them in TEST env...

could this be implemented using flyway? (running flyway on the same scripts but on different instance\server and different flyway_schema_history table?)

Comment: Do you want your Test server to be built from scratch, or is this server a copy of production that is used to "rehearse" the upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for missing your question. The answer is yes. Using Flyway you can define a set of migration scripts that can run against any target.